Evaluation break in WolframScript
Astonishingly, I couldn't find this either by googling or tag search here.
CTRL-C completely closes WolframScript (on my Windows 10). But I just want to break the evaluation (if it takes too long). And maybe try another evaluation scheme (with variables still assigned). How can I do that?

Ctrl + Break or Ctrl + . does not work?

@azerbajdzan:  Ctrl + .  has no effect. What is "break" on a German kezboard? :-)

I have on my keyboard a key called Pause/Break and it works to abort evaluation if I run code from kernel (without front-end). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#/media/File:LenovoKeyboard.jpg rightmost key in the uppermost row.

@azerbajdzan: Ah, THAT one - this is also on my German keyboard and I never used it in 30 years of computing :-) But no, same thing as CTRL-C. Window closes immediately.
